# Deixar á pagina Html de acordo com que a janela do navegador vai diminuir ou aumentar

Tags: html

Eae galera, preciso que me ajudem por que preciso deixar minha página html de acordo com o tamanho da janela...

Comment: Sendo mais específico, deixar o layout responsivo...

Answer (score 1):

Olá

A pergunta está meio nebulosa. Mas se for em relação a altura e largura, você pode utilizar medidas relativas vw e vh.

Vw significa Viewport Wirth que define a largura de acordo com tamanho da tela de visualização.

Vh significa Viewport Height que define a altura de acordo com o tamanho da tela de visualização.

No teu caso pode usar:

body {
       min-width: 100vw;
       min-height: 100vh;
}

Valeu

Comment: Eu também pensei assim mais o que eu me emcabulo e pq eu diminuo a janela mais os elementos ficam se adaptando. Queria deixar minha página assim, acho que com css posso fazer...